# Does this integral converge or diverge? Can you help me to integrate this?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Does this integral converge or diverge?
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}+\cos x}\,dx$$
I tried to simplify it using trigonometric functions, but I got lost.

Comment: @RobertZ yeees, Thank yoou so much

Comment: This is not integrable in elementary way. Mathematica failed.

Comment: @Jon how did you conclude that?

Comment: I think it tends to $$-\infty$$

Comment: This can be seen at a first inspection but, anyway, I checked with some CAS tools.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That is correct. It is enough to check it numerically.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the convergence/divergence. Note that by integration by parts,
$$\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos (x)}{\sqrt{x}+\cos (x)}\,dx&=
\left[\frac{\sin (x)}{\sqrt{x}+\cos (x)}\right]_1^{\infty}-
\int_1^{\infty}\sin(x)\cdot\frac{\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}{(\sqrt{x}+\cos x)^2}\,dx\\
&=
\left[\frac{\sin (x)}{\sqrt{x}+\cos (x)}\right]_1^{\infty}-
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{(\sqrt{x}+\cos x)^2}\,dx+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}+\cos x)^2}\,dx
\end{align}$$
Now  the last integral is convergent, whereas 
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{(\sqrt{x}+\cos x)^2}\,dx\geq \int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{(\sqrt{x}+1)^2}\,dx\geq \int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{4x}\,dx.$$
It remains to show that the integral on the right is divergent which implies that the given integral diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: I already tried integration by parts, but I did not reach to any conclusion.

Comment: Can we write also as $\left|\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}+\cos x}\,dx\right|\le\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx$ showing no convergence?

Comment: do you use integration by parts to show that the integral on the left is divergent?

Comment: @Jon ... No. We can write $\left|\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}+\cos x}\,dx\right|\le\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx$ but that gives us no information about convergence.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks.